# Android studio not catching exceptions, maybe it is firebase?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Debugging my app, android studio is not catching fatal exceptions and I just get "Your application has closed", and looking at Android monitor, I don't see anything regarding an exception, maybe I see something about Logging event(FE), so maybe by guess is that maybe firebase is catching exceptions which works great for deployed applications, but not for running in debugger.

Can someone tell me how I can keep both deployed exception catching with firebase, but also still allow exceptions to be caught when running in android studio debugger.

Comment: Please post important parts of the activity in question.

Comment: It isn't specific to any activity, but it is something with the overall application.  For example if I put something like String test = null; test.isEmpty();  Which causes a crash anywhere in the application, all I see is "your aplication has stopped" and nothing in android monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In logcat set it to "No filter" (on the left hand side drop down list) and filter by you app package name
This way you can see your logs after the process has stopped

Comment: Thanks this was it.  It had been set only on Firebase.