# How to fix logcat for app not showing in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat

When I run my app on my Galaxy S7, nothing shows in the logcat in Android Studio. Not even while debugging. If I use another device, I can see the logcat. On one device (Asus Padfone Android version 4.4.2) I can run my app from Android Studio and everything works fine. When I run it on my S7(Different Android version: 7.0) the app crashes in some activities but since the logcat doesn't show I can't see what the problem is. How can I get the logcat to show so I can see the issues? I've tried killing adb processes and restarting the adb server. I've invalidated cache in Android Studio. Nothing works. I was able to see the logcat prior to my S7 updating. I'm using Android Studio 2.3.1. All sdk packages are downloaded and up to date.

Note: I posted this question here because I believe it to be more relevant to programming than hardware.

Comment: Try changing the filter on your logcat
See here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/43564328/6301831

Comment: @pantos27 I tried changing the filter setting already. Unfortunately that didn't work either. :/

Comment: Tools -> Android -> Enable ADB Integration (uncheck wait a minute and check again)

Comment: check the answer on this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31226686/android-studio-my-app-not-showing-in-logcat-out-put